# how to fill current dropdown list with jquery onclick?

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I know there are lots of solutions for chained dropdown lists but i'm trying to create something a little bit different than usual.

Menu before user click:

```
<select>
 <option>Choose Something</option>
</select>
```

Menu after user clicked:

```
<select>
<option>Loading options</option>
</select>
```

Menu after options loaded from server:

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
```

The problem is after menu filled, its size is small and other items don't appear until second click.

Is there a solution with that ?

Comment: For what the second click is for ?

Comment: Did you try to do a focus and/or blur after the loading of new elements is completed? I think this could do the trick

Comment: @AkhilThayyil actually it shouldn't be necessary but although items are loaded and their presence can verified via tools like firebug, size of opened dropdown list remains small for seeing loaded items.

Comment: If the size only matters, then change the with of the select to some suitable value; ie <select style="width:150px;">

Comment: @motto I know it is an old one, but would help if you were able to find what the reason was and how you resolved it.

Comment: I don't remember exactly. check dropdown in mersinemlakrehberi.com may be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a some workaround. Might help you.

HTML (empty `option` as place holders)

```
<select>
  <option>Select Something</option>
  <option>&nbsp;</option> 
  <option>&nbsp;</option>
  <option>&nbsp;</option>
</select>​
```

JavaScript

```
var clickCount = 0;
$("select").click(function(e) {
   if (clickCount == 0) $("select").empty().html("<option>Loading options</option>");
   clickCount++;
   if (clickCount == 1) {
       $("select").click();
       return;
   }
   if (clickCount == 2) {
       $("select").empty().html("<option>Select Something</option><option>1</option> <option>2</option> <option>3</option><option>4</option> ");
       $("select :nth-child(1)").attr("selected", "selected");
   }
});​
```

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/bSPEY/1/) or [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/bSPEY/2/) on jsfiddle.net.

Hope this works out for you.

Comment: Yes that's a workaround but i don't think it's a proper solution what i was looking for.

Comment: In that case you will have to create your own dropdown, with help of div and image

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").click(function(){ 
    $("select").empty().append("<option>Loading options</option>");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.your_server.com/your_page',
        success: function (data) {
            $("select").empty().append(data); //your data being: <option>1</option> <option>2</option> <option>3</option><option>4</option>

        }
    })        
})
```